# Problem migrating code from Angular 5 to Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular7, rxjs6

I am trying to migrate some code from Angular 5 to Angular 7. I tried the official update guide, but not everything was migrated. So I tried it manually, but I can not get it to work.

This is  Angular 5 Code

```js
getNodes(): Observable < Node[] > {
   return Observable.create(obs => {
     ros.getNodes(data => {
      obs.next(data);
      obs.complete();
     });
   }).flatMap(data => {
     return Observable.forkJoin(data.map(name => Observable.create(obs => {
       const detailClient = new ROSLIB.Service({
         ros: ros,
         name: '/rosapi/node_details',
         serviceType: 'rosapi/NodeDetails'
       });
       const request = new ROSLIB.ServiceRequest({ node: name });
       detailClient.callService(request, data2 => {
         obs.next({ name, subscribing: data2.subscribing });
         obs.complete();
       });
     })));
   });
 }
 loadData(): void {
   Observable.forkJoin(this.getNodes()).subscribe(([nodes]) => {
     //this.data.nodes = nodes;
     console.log(nodes);
   });
 }
```

And the output of console.log is the following and the new Angular 7 code should look like the same

```js
[
  {
    "name": "/mission_controller"
  },
  {
    "name": "/mavros"
  },
  {
    "name": "/pose_analyser"
  }
]
```

This is what I tried, but it gives me the error "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '{}'"

```js
getNodes(): Observable<Node[]> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    ros.getNodes(data => {
      obs.next(data);
      obs.complete();
    });
  }).pipe(mergeMap( data => {
    return forkJoin(data.pipe(map(name => Observable.create(obs => {
      const detailClient = new ROSLIB.Service({
        ros: ros,
        name: '/rosapi/node_details',
        serviceType: 'rosapi/NodeDetails'
      });
      const request = new ROSLIB.ServiceRequest({ node: name });
      detailClient.callService(request, data2 => {
        obs.next({ name });
        obs.complete();
      });
    }))));
  }));
}
loadNodes(): void {
  forkJoin(this.getNodes()).subscribe(([nodes]) => {
    console.log(nodes);      
  });
}
```

I hope somebody can help me

Best regards

newsub7

Comment: You're doing `data.pipe`, what type is `data`?

Comment: console.log(data) says its an array. when I hover it with my cursor in sublimetext it shows "(parameter) data:  {}"

Comment: Well an array doesn't have a `pipe` function

Comment: hmm ok do you have any idea how i can change it, so that it works?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? If you want to `map` it, arrays **do** have a `map` function, so you could use `map` without needing `pipe`

Comment: yeah i just wan to map it, but when I use data.map(...) and compile it, I get the error Property 'map' does not exist on type {} ...

Comment: Change `mergeMap( data => {` to `mergeMap((data: any[]) => {`

Comment: oh my god of course. I think I'm stupid.... thanks man. it works